# Need help with a MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of `Products` that looks like so:

```
|    id   |    Description   |   Price    |
|    1    |  dinglehopper    |    2.99    |
|    2    |  flux capacitor  |   48.99    |
|    3    |  thing1          |   48.99    |
```

And so on...

Then I have an `OrderLineItem` table which, as you can guess, links each item in an order to the product:

```
|    id   |    productID     |   OrderID  |
|    43   |  1               |    12      |
|    44   |  2               |    12      |
|    52   |  3               |    15      |
```

So, as you can see, order #12 contains a dinglehopper and flux capacitor.  How can I get this information in a single query?  I just want ALL the products associated with a given OrderID in the OrderLineItem table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be by

```
select p.description,p.id,o.irderId 
from 
    `orderLineItem` o, `product` p 
where 
    p.id = o.productId;
```

or

```
select p.description,p.id,o.irderId 
from `orderLineItem` o
join  `product` p 
on p.id = o.productId;
```

Comment: How am I supposed to filter the returned products down to a specific order ID?  I made a change to my question to hopefully make it clearer.  I only want products 1 and 2 returned because thats what's associated with order 12.

Comment: Yes and they don't work 100%.  You got me part of the way there.  This query works: SELECT Products.Description, Products.Price, OrderLineItem.OrderID
FROM OrderLineItem
JOIN Products ON Products.ID = OrderLineItem.productID
WHERE OrderLineItem.OrderID = '12'

Comment: @Pete: I can expect this from you. Its easy to write a where as a part of query.

Comment: Don't be so sure.  I'm not that well versed which is why I asked for help here to begin with.  Either way, thanks for getting me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN :)

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Wouldn't a left join return all rows on the left table?  Seeing as how I don't want ALL rows on ANY table, how is this helpful?  If I'm mistaken, please elaborate.

Comment: Oh man you are right, I completely misread your question.  My fault.  Harry Joys first answer will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

@Pete About "single" query part, you should make VIEW from this join, if really going to use a lot.